# Invalid Name Error - Crystal Reports in VB6

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

I'm trying to set the title of a crystal report in `VB6`, but I keep being shown an error.

The parameter field that I want to set the text of is called `txtTitle`.

However, when running this code, it gives an error saying

> Invalid Name

```
If opt_sales_ledger.Value = True Then
 crxReport.ParameterFields.GetItemByName("txtTitle").AddCurrentValue ("List of Sales Ledger Accounts")
ElseIf opt_purchase_ledger.Value = True Then
 crxReport.ParameterFields.GetItemByName("txtTitle").AddCurrentValue ("List of Purchase Ledger Accounts")
End If
```

What's causing the error?

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: @reds no, the answer below didn't solve it

Answer (score 0):

Crystal is looking for a "parameter" type field called "txtTitle" and it cannot locate it.  I usually use formulas for this purpose, in other words "txtTitle" would be a formula in the report and defined and/or initialized as a stringVar

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this way:

```
crxReport.ParameterFields(1).AddCurrentValue ("your_first_parameter_value")
crxReport.ParameterFields(2).AddCurrentValue ("your_second_parameter_value")
```

Good luck!